# getting error message after: SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message

Tags: java, soap, saaj

I get "SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message
" when I try to send a SOAP message to a specific webservice. 
I know this is because I get an error message back, but I want to be able to read that error message(or more specificly let java read it, so I can log it in a db).

is there any way the exception can give me the html response I get?
(I can't change or access the serverside code)

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:157)
    at my own code.executeSOAPMessage()
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:151)
... 27 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:602)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:86)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:404)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection$PriviledgedPost.run(HttpSOAPConnection.java:180)
... 29 more
```

Comment: could you please add stacktrace of that error?

Comment: You can set `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump` to true. But i don't know any way to write full __html__ response to database. Maybe someone else help you.